What RAM and cabinet would you recommend for MSI X670-P with Ryzen 5 8600G?
My current desktop PC is terribly outdated and I'm looking to build a new one based on the AMD Ryzen 5 8600G processor and MSI PRO X670-P as the motherboard (AM5 socket).

What DDR5 RAM specs should I look for? Although the AMD specs rate the speed at 5200MT/s, I see that folks are using 6000MT/s and higher speed RAMs. What speeds can I use without issues with the CPU-Motherboard combination I chose? (Should I limit myself to 6000MT/s or is it okay to use higher speeds?) And what CAS latency would be better - I see they're available with CL30/32/36/40 ...?. I plan to start with 32GB and expand later, if needed.
What are affordable or inexpensive cabinets that utilize the features of the PRO X670-P motherboard - ports, IO connections, cooling, audio, etc? I am planning to use one Crucial P3 1TB PCIe 4.0 NVMe SSD, and from my older PC- some SATA SSDs, and already have a Coolermaster G700 GoldPSU.

